# Bootstrap get glyphicon code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

My task is to get code from bootstrap glyphicon element (for example "\e020").

I've tried the following approach:

html:

```
<div id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div>
```

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle($('#glyph')[0], ':before').content);
});
```

but here I can achieve only the character itself, not the original code.

Is there a way to get the string of "\e020"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toString` method with `16` parameter to transform char to HEX:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle($('#glyph')[0], ':before').content
var result = '\\' + content.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);    
alert(result);
```

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbxfq7j8/2/)